# String.equalsIgnoreCase(...) equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to test 2 strings for equality in Ruby in a case insensitive manner.

In languages, such as [Fantom](http://fantom-lang.org/), you simply write:

```
string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)
```

What's the ***idiomatic*** way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [casecmp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp)

```
"Test".casecmp("teST")
=> 0

"Test".casecmp("teST2")
=> -1
```

So to test for equality, you can do:

```
if str.casecmp(str2).zero?
  # strings are equal
end
```

Comment: You could add `.zero?` at the end.

Comment: I like the addition of `.zero?`, I've not come across that before.

Comment: `Fixnum#nonzero?` and `Fixnum#zero?` are the idiomatic way to avoid using 0 in an if condition which expects true or false, because the 0 value is considered true in that context.

Comment: Surely 'casecmp' suggests that case is important. Shouldn't this have been called 'nocasecmp'? :)

Answer (score 4):

Though there is [`casecmp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-casecmp):

```
0 == s1.casecmp(s2) # strings equal
```

I personally prefer

```
s1.downcase == s2.downcase
```

Comment: Your preferred way is not an equivalent, however. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Huh, there are uses of `String#match` suggested around. Compare to those, mine is a stark equivalent :-)

Comment: I mean the "downcase" approach. It doesn't fit the signature `s1.op(s2)`. Anyway, never mind. :)

Comment: I think the intention of this code is far clearer than the `casecmp` method in the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure it is and that’s why I do prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the strings to lowercase and then compare

```
a.downcase == b.downcase
```

Or, if you prefer, to uppercase

```
a.upcase == b.upcase
```

Comment: While this solution is quite obvious, converting both objects for a simple comparison... just seems a bit over-the-top for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-match) method :

```
s = "Test"
s.match(/teST/i) # => #<MatchData "Test">
s.match(/teST2/i) # => nil
```

Remember in Ruby all objects are has the truth value, except `nil` and `false`. So you can use this trick also to perform conditional testing.

Comment: This solution is by far the most readable and very explicit. But I just don't feel it's the idiomatic `Ruby` way...

Comment: @SteveEynon I use this technique..as it is very basic.. and easy to use. :)